# Find upper bound for stepsize h in Runge Kutta method

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I am trying to solve this exercise.

Consider the following initial value problem $$ y^{\prime} (t) = \lambda y (t) \, \text{for} \, t \in [0; T] ; y (0) = y_0; $$ with $T  > 0, y_0 \in \mathbb{R} $ and $ \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Consider the explicit Euler method. Is it possible to specify a boundry for the stepsize $h > 0$ for $$ a) \lambda = 3 + 3i; \, b) \lambda = -3 + 3i \, \text{where} \, i^2 = -1;  $$ so that the method outputs a stable numerical solution?

I have tried to solve this exercise over the stability function of the Runge Kutta Method. It is known that $$ R(z) = 1+z$$ with $z = \lambda h$. And it is also known that $\vert Re(z) \vert < 1$ sould hold, if we want a stable method.

Thus, $$ \vert Re(z) \vert = \vert 1+z \vert = \vert 1+ \lambda h \vert \leq 1 + h \vert \lambda \vert \overset{a)}{=} 1+ h \vert 3+3i \vert = 1 + h \sqrt{18} \overset{!}{<} 1  \Rightarrow h<0$$

That is not possible because $h>0$

So, how can I handle this exercise? Or do I make a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should not use the triangle inequality. In fact, for $\lambda=3+3i$,
$$ |1+\lambda h|=|1+(3+3i)h|=|(1+3h)+3hi|=\sqrt{(1+3h)^2+(3h)^2}>1$$
for $h>0$. It means that the method is unstable for  $\lambda=3+3i$. For $\lambda=-3+3i$,
$$ |1+\lambda h|=|1+(-3+3i)h|=|(1-3h)+3hi|=\sqrt{(1-3h)^2+(3h)^2}<1$$
gives
$$ 18h^2-6h<0 $$
whose solution is $0<h<\frac13$. Thus if $0<h<\frac13$, the method is stable for  $\lambda=-3+3i$.

Comment: Thank you xpaul !

Comment: I am trying to show the same for $Re(z) = \frac{1+ 1/2 z + 1/12 z^2}{1 - 1/2 z + 1/12 z^2}$. This is a A-stable implicit Runge Kutta Method and shoul at least for $ \lambda = -3 +3i$ stable. But I calculated the solution $ - \sqrt{2/3}i < h< 0$. This is wrong or not? The stepsize could not be in $\mathbb{C}$.